# Optional wrapper around API key swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm attempting to test a server response using an API key taken from a `.plist` file. When I print out the key from the from the request header, it has an optional wrapper: `Optional([App-Token: apikey1234567]))`. I'm not getting a response, which I think is because the key is being passed in this form. A little new to Swift. How can I pass this so it isn't optional? Relevant code below:

```
var key: String!

let baseURL: String = ("https://apiurl.com/").stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

override init() {
    path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("APIkey", ofType: "plist")
    dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)
    key = dict!.objectForKey("APIkey") as! String
    super.init()
}

func updateJSON() {
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: baseURL)!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    request.setValue(key, forHTTPHeaderField:"App-Token")
    // This prints out the 'Optional([App-Token: apikey1234567]))'
    println("\(request.allHTTPHeaderFields))")
    var dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        var error: NSError?
        if (error != nil) {
            println("\(error)")
        } else {
            self.jsonObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &error) as? NSDictionary
            println("\(self.jsonObject)")
        }

    })
    dataTask.resume()
}
```

UPDATE: I was getting `nil` because `jsonObject` was being cast as an `NSDictionary`. When I changed its type to `AnyObject` the response came back.

Comment: Have you tried dict!.objectForKey("APIkey") as! String!  ?

Comment: Just tried. Still the optional wrapper.

Comment: How about key as! String! in update JSON method ? strange that it is optional since you declared it as non optional and casted string from dict as non optional...

Comment: Same. And when I check `request.valueForHTTPHeaderField("App-Token")` I get `Optional("apikey1234567")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions valueForHTTPHeaderField and allHTTPHeaderFields - return optionals, it doesn't mean the key you put in is optional. from Swift NSURLRequest file:

```
func valueForHTTPHeaderField(field: String) -> String?

var allHTTPHeaderFields: [String : String]?
```

Check value of key by adding print after setting it in init:

```
var key: String!

let baseURL: String = ("https://apiurl.com/").stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

override init() {
    path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("APIkey", ofType: "plist")
    dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)
    key = dict!.objectForKey("APIkey") as! String
    println("On init Key = \(key)")       // Check key value here is it optional?
    super.init()
}
```

Also:  dataTaskWithRequest returns optional so at least optional chain:

dataTask?.resume()

You also have an new error:NSError created in completion of task when it already returns an error, it appears you mean to create this error for JSON parse? best to name it different to avoid any ambiguity.  Some var can be let because never mutated -session, request, dataTask.

```
func updateJSON() {
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: baseURL)!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    request.setValue(key, forHTTPHeaderField:"App-Token")
    // This prints out the 'Optional([App-Token: apikey1234567]))'
    println("\(request.allHTTPHeaderFields))")

    let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            println("\(error)")
        } else {
            var jsonError: NSError?
            self.jsonObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: & jsonError) as? NSDictionary
            println("\(self.jsonObject)")
        }

    })
    dataTask?.resume()
}
```

(NB: I only have machine with xcode 7 and swift 2 installed at this moment, but i don't think any of these things have changed since Swift 1.2)

Comment: Good tips. Thanks. The API must be returning nil for some other reason.